# How to write csv data to Bigquery table where each file have different no. of column and we want common columns to load from each file in Apache Beam?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have multiple csv files in a GCS bucket.
Each file have different number of columns and order of columns are also different.
I want to load only common columns from all this files to Bigquery.

Can anyone suggest some approach to get this done using Apache Beam?

Comment: I proposed you an answer and a solution, may you check it please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `csv` `Dict` reader with `Apache Beam` to read all the input files.

The result will be a `PCollection` of `Dict`.

Then you can apply a transformation if needed.

You can also directly use the `BigQuery` output connector with an option allowing to ignore extra fields.

Example of `CSV` `Dict` reader with `Beam` :

```py
import codecs
from _csv import QUOTE_ALL
from typing import Iterable, Dict

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import PCollection
from apache_beam.io import fileio
from apache_beam.io.filesystem import CompressionTypes
from apache_beam.io.filesystems import FileSystems as beam_fs


class ReadCsvFiles(beam.PTransform):
    """
    IO transform that allow to read a CSV file with Apache Beam as PCollection of Dict[str, str].
    This transform takes an input pattern and a compression type and uses Beam FileSystem class to load file from GCS.

    For the uncompressed compression, the CSV files matching the pattern are load.
    In this case, the file is decoded as iterable

    For GZIP compression, the GZIP files matching the pattern are load.
    In this case the file is recovered with uncompressed to prevent Beam to uncompressed because there are errors
    The uncompression is done manually in the code after the retrieval of file

    """

    def __init__(self,
                 file_pattern: str,
                 compression_type: CompressionTypes,
                 delimiter=',',
                 quotechar='"',
                 doublequote=True,
                 skipinitialspace=False,
                 lineterminator='\n',
                 quoting=QUOTE_ALL):
        super().__init__()
        self._file_pattern = file_pattern
        self._compression_type = compression_type
        self._delimiter = delimiter
        self._quotechar = quotechar
        self._doublequote = doublequote
        self._skipinitialspace = skipinitialspace
        self._lineterminator = lineterminator
        self._quoting = quoting

    def expand(self, pbegin: beam.pvalue.PBegin) -> PCollection[Dict[str, str]]:
        return (
                pbegin
                | 'Match files' >> fileio.MatchFiles(self._file_pattern)
                | 'Read CSV lines' >> beam.FlatMap(self._read_csv_lines_as_dicts)
        )

    def _get_csv_reader(self, result_file_as_iterator):
        import csv
        return csv.DictReader(
            result_file_as_iterator,
            delimiter=self._delimiter,
            quotechar=self._quotechar,
            doublequote=self._doublequote,
            skipinitialspace=self._skipinitialspace,
            lineterminator=self._lineterminator,
            quoting=self._quoting)

    def _read_csv_lines_as_dicts(self, readable_file_metadata) -> Iterable[Dict[str, str]]:
        """
        Beam reads files as bytes, but csv expects strings,
        so we need to decode the bytes into utf-8 strings.

        For GZIP files the uncompression is done in our code instead Beam code, to prevent errors.
        """
        with beam_fs.open(readable_file_metadata.path, compression_type=CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED) as f:
            import gzip
            if self._compression_type == CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED:
                for row in self._get_csv_reader(codecs.iterdecode(f, 'utf-8')):
                    yield dict(row)
            else:
                with gzip.open(f, "rt") as gzip_text_io_wrapper:
                    for row in self._get_csv_reader(gzip_text_io_wrapper):
                        yield dict(row)
```

Example with a pseudo code in the `Beam` pipeline :

```py
def run():
    my_pipeline_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(MyPipelineOptions)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        
        (
                p
                | 'Read CSV files' >> ReadCsvFiles("gs://bucket/folder/*.csv", CompressionTypes.UNCOMPRESSED)
                | "Write to output table" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            ignore_unknown_columns=True,
            project='project_id',
            dataset='dataset',
            table='table',
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        )
```

- The `WriteToBigQuery` output connector write the result to a `BigQuery` table. It's based on a `PCollection` of `Dict`.
- I used the `ignore_unknown_columns` as True to ignore extra fields, if this option is passed as False, the `Dict` should match exactly the structure of the `BigQuery` table. It's not the case for you, that's why I proposed this option. If this solution is not possible in your case, you can apply a specific transformation from a `Dict` to another `Dict` with your logic.